# How to escape a Hungry Node in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-thaumcraft

How can I escape the grasp of a [Hungry Node](http://thaumcraft-3.wikia.com/wiki/Nodes#Types_of_Nodes) and survive?

Comment: @Downvoters, explain.

Comment: Downvoters do not need to explain. It could be useful if they did, but without a comment a downvote means "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: @RoryAlsop The only thing I tried to do was to share my knowledge.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Was just browsing and saw your comment so thought I'd help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Open Blocks [Hang Glider](http://ftbwiki.org/Hang_Glider), when you get caught in a Hungry Node while using it, you'll get sucked in, but you won't be flung around like a ragdoll. Instead you'll just hang in the middle of the node. Eventually you'll get launched in the air, but since you still have your Hang Glider open, you'll be safe from the fall.

If you don't have Open Blocks installed, you can use Ender Pearls to teleport away, this is not very reliable though and can possibly get you killed instead.

Answer (score 1):

how about putting your node in a jar, you don't have to escape from something that's not there:

Node In A Jar:
This Research allows you to bottle up Nodes, and move them to wherever you want to place them.

Warded jars have proven themselves capable of storing all manner of mundane and mystical things, and you believe you have discovered another use for them - trapping aura nodes.

By constructing a large version of a jar around a node and enacting the proper mystical formula with your wand, the node will become trapped inside the construct which will quickly shrink to a more manageable size. The jar can then be safely picked up and moved around, but the initial trapping spell does have a very good chance of damageing the node.

While trapped the node is kept suspended and will not regenerate vis, nor can vis be drawn from it.

It is possible to free the node from the jar by placing it in the world and clicking on it with a wand. The jar will be destroyed in the process.

To capture a Node, you must place a multi-layered construct directly around it, as shown in the picture on the right.

> Layer 1 (upper layer): 9 Wooden Slabs.
>
> Layer 2: 9 Glass.
>
> Layer 3 (Node level: 8 Glass, surrounding the Node.
>
> Layer 4: 9 Glass

[image: Node In A Jar]

Then click on the construct with your Wand. This consumes 70 of each Primal Aspect, so you cannot do this with a lesser Wand only.

Once this is done, the Node can be picked up, like you would a Warded Jar.

Required Research: Node Preserver
Node In A Jar

> 30px Auram
>
> 30px Lucrum
>
> Motus
>
> Permutatio

Notes:

Moving a Node has a good chance of lowering its quality: a Bright Node may devolve into a Normal one, or a Normal Node into a Fading one. Therefore, moving already Fading Nodes isn't advised.

Thaumcraft 4 needed.

Comment: A hungry node is almost impossible to put in a jar, the glass will disappear faster than you can place it! The only way to do this is by encasing the node in obsidian (which the node doesn't eat) and using the wand of equal trade to switch it to the glass you need very quickly. This way works like 1/5 of the time and you die a lot.

Comment: thats true, diden't say it was easy. still is a hungry node.